# List main directory and its sub-directories using directory name property in power shell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have the following tree structure of a folder called test.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to list the main directory and its sub-directories under the column directory name using the Get-ChildItem property(Code is shown below).

Here's the code that I wrote in powershell :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test -Recurse | Select-Object directoryname, Name, LastWriteTime, CreationTime | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\filetxt.csv' -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

What I achieved is the following :
[image]

As you can see, the directory name for Folder1 and Folder2 is missing and it should've been taken the same name of the path. Similarly for SubFolder1, the directory name should be Main Path\Folder1 and etc...  My expected result is the following :
[image]

Can someone please help me find a solution for the following problem ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders do not have a property "directoryname". You can use a calculated property with a `Split-Path` to extract the information you're after.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\sample\test-files -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name='Path';Expression={Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Parent}},Name, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, @{Name='Extension';Expression={if (-not $_.PSIsContainer) {$_.Extension}}}
```

And BTW: Folders actually do not have a "LastWriteTime". They show the "LastWriteTime" from the newest file they contain. ;-)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It perfectly works. However, I have a question regarding the extension of the files. In the large folder that I have on my desktop I have several subfolders containing files with different extensions (example : .csv, .pdf, .xls). Some of these files are named with '.' inside . I want to try to add an extension column but it's not working. Do you have any clue how to do that ?

Comment: Yes it works thanks. However, if the name was a Folder and it contains a "." the extension of that will be the "." and everything after the point. Do you know how can exclude the extension on for the folders ?

Comment: Did you try it? Folders do not have extensions. If they have dots '**.**' in their names it's part of their name ... not an extension. Try it please.

Comment: Yes I did try it. It still shows in the extension for the folder everything after the point. Example I have a folder called coursera_lectures12.HongKong . Once I run the code, what I see in the extension column is ".HongKong" and I need to find a way or condition to remove such senario

Comment: Hmmm ... strange ... but ok, no Problem. Changed the code again.  I'd recommend for you to learn [about calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Can you please explain to me what this line of code does Expression={if (-not $_.PSIsContainer) {$_.Extension}. Like step by step, what does the -not expression do and onward ? Sorry for asking a lot , I am just newbie to powershell

Comment: I posted a link to the according help topic in my last comment. Please read the help.